# Add Table to Specified Site Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

So I have a table that I want to add using Javascript to a webpage (set of webpages in fact, each with different data). 
One example is: 
http://www.aljazeera.com/sport/brazil2014/2014/06/nigeria-send-bosnia-herzegovina-packing-2014621234148521134.html
I want to add my table to the right hand side column (the one which starts with "Fixtures.." anywhere, as long as it appears!
Suppose this is the how I create my table:

```
function createTable(list){

    var body = document.body, tbl  = document.createElement('table');
    tbl.setAttribute("style", "border: 0px solid #ccc;position:absolute;top:00px;right:0px;");

    for(var i = 0; i < ((list.length) ); i++){
        var tr = tbl.insertRow();
        for(var j = 0; j < 1; j++){
            var td = tr.insertCell();
            var a = document.createElement('a');
                    var linkText = document.createTextNode((list[i]));
            a.appendChild(linkText);
            a.title = list[i];
         td.appendChild(a);
        }
    }
    tbl.style.width='25%';
    body.appendChild(tbl);
}

createTable(["TEST1", "TEST2"])
```

(I have looped and added info to it, so that's not a problem).
I tried creating new divs, inserting my table, but it never appears there. I'm running out of ideas; any help would do, thank you!

Comment: The table doesn't appear, but did you check the code? does the code apeear? I mean, is it a "css" problem or a js "break" problem?

Comment: I think it's a css problem, because for a specific className, when I added the table, it appeared but over another element (specifically, the Twitter element on the RHS).

Comment: can you see the table code when looking the code? If Yes, then try to "play" with inline css to make it visible (position:absolute, z-index:9999....)

Comment: That's the problem; I can't see it at all. And will the playing guarantee the table always appears on any  http://www.aljazeera.com/* article (since that's what I'm looking for)? Thank you ^_^

Comment: And there is no error on console? Then we should see code to play with

Comment: Have you remembered to `parentNode.appendChild(tbl);`? Show all relevant code, so we're best able to help.

Comment: My bad; I've posted some code just now. Thanks again^^

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your problem. Maybe you have to clarify your question. Your provided code works pretty well. To integrate your table below "FIXTURES" just remove the inline CSS (at least the absolute positioning) and replace `body.appendChild(...)` with:

```
var container = document.querySelector('#ctl00_ctl05_layout1 ._boxBody.box_bodyFalseTrue');
container.insertBefore(tbl, container.firstChild);
```

and it will appear topmost below the "FIXTURES" header.